# How to loop through a class and identify every element with a specific classlist attribute

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have the following code - which creates 4 spans within a class, and allows a user to click on the spans they're interested in - which then turns the span a different color to indicate that it has been clicked.

```html
    <head>
        <style>
            .tagger1010 span 
            {
    padding: 6px 10px;
    background: #D0E8E4;
    border-radius: 18px;
    color: #000000;
    font-family: Roboto;
    font-size: 12px;
    margin: 0 4px 8px 0;
    font-weight: 500;
    display: inline-block;
    word-wrap: break-word;
    white-space: normal;
              cursor: pointer;
            user-select: none;
border: 1px solid BBD0CD;

            }
    
            .tagger1010 span.is-active {
                background-color: #008fde;
                color: #ffffff;

            }
            
            .tagger1010 span:hover {
                background-color: #008fde;
                color: #ffffff;
            }
        </style>

<body>
    
<div class="tagger1010">
  <span>Google</span>
  <span>Microsoft</span>
  <span>Facebook</span>
  <span>LinkedIn</span>
</div>

<div class="as-console-wrapper"></div>
<div class="as-console"></div>  
 <script type="text/javascript">
       const changeColor = (evt) => {
  if (evt.currentTarget.classList.contains("is-active")) {
    evt.currentTarget.classList.remove("is-active");
  } else {
    evt.currentTarget.classList.add("is-active");
  }
};
const EL_tagger1010_children = document.querySelectorAll(".tagger1010 span");
EL_tagger1010_children.forEach(EL => EL.addEventListener("click", changeColor));

var tags = ["Microsoft","Facebook"];
var spans = div.getElementsByTagName("span");

for(i=0;i<tags.length;i++)
{
  if(spans.includes(tags[i])){
  //Find the span whose text is tags[i], and add is-active to it's classList 
 }
 }
    </script>
    
    <div class="as-console-wrapper">
    <div class="as-console">
    
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

When a user clicks on one of the spans, it is highlighted blue. Next, I want the user to save the things they have highlighted. To do that, is there a quick way to identify which spans in the class have attribute "is-active?"

Comment: `div.getElementsByTagName` --> "Uncaught ReferenceError: div is not defined"

Answer (score 1):

use `getElementsByClassname` The documentation for that can be found [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName).

```js
var elements = document.getElementsByClassName('is-active');
```

This also would've been very easy to just search for.

Comment: When I run that, and then try to output "elements" to read what's in it, I get [object HTMLCollection]

Comment: @youewew please look how it is used in the documentation i linked

Comment: I see. Thanks. I think what I need is missing from that documentation (or maybe I'm just missing it) - I can't see how to store an array of the innerHTML text of each span that has the is-active class.

Comment: @youewew you can treat that object like an array, it does the same thing. If you want the first one do `elements[0]` and so on.